# Syntax Error - Unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' with submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

I have a `SyntaxError`. I'm creating a form using form_tag and submit_tag.

The SyntaxError is

```
SyntaxError at /products
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Normally, I wouldn't ask for help on this, but I cannot find where the syntax error is. It works, without the submit_tag.

```
<%= form_tag Product.new do |f| %>

  <div class = "price">

    <%= label_tag :price %>
    $<%= number_field_tag :price %>

    <%= submit_tag "Submit %>

  </div>

<% end %>

<div id="slider"></div>
```

I have double checked, triple checked and 4 time checked, but cannot find out how this is a syntax error. It looks like this isn't an issue with syntax but something else.

Comment: Do you notice that you have not closed the `Submit` `<%= submit_tag "Submit" %>`

Comment: What is `$` after label_tag?

Comment: Can't believe I missed that one. This question should be downvoted

Comment: @RMilushev That's ok.. It is printing the price with `$` preceded..

Comment: Don't blame yourself, take a break, relax, and then come back to work.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enclose the string. Close it.

```
<%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I can't believe I missed that.